# Google AppEngine unable to defer a sendmail job to default taskqueue , receives unauthorized sender error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sendmail, task-queue

Hi am trying to defer sending mail via sendmail. 
Am able to send mail no problem. 
As soon as I try `deferred.defer(send_invitation,recipient)`, it stops working.

I can see the tasks retrying to  max allowed limit, and the logs show:

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 1136, in send
    raise ERROR_MAP[e.application_error](e.error_detail)
InvalidSenderError: Unauthorized sender
```

Does this mean that if a sendmail job is sent to the default queue (or any queue), it is no longer considered as being sent from the original sender, and that the new sender (i.e. the queue) is not authorized??

Without using `deferred.defer` the mail is sent, both with project owner's email, and default appengine service account. Both accounts have needed permissions/roles.

```
    import webapp2
    from google.appengine.ext import deferred
    import jinja2
    import os
    import datetime
    from google.appengine.api import users, mail


    recipient ='xxxxxx@xxxx.com'

    user = users.GetCurrentUser().email()

    print "THIS IS THE CURRENT USER %s" %user


    def send_invitation(recipient):
                print "In the def user email is %s" %user

                mail.send_mail(sender=user,to=recipient, subject='You\'re invited!',body='''You have been invited to join our community...''')



    class SendInvitationHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        print "This is user within the class %s" %user
        def get(self):
            user = users.GetCurrentUser().email()
            tempalte_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.getcwd()))
            current_time =  datetime.datetime.now()
            template = tempalte_env.get_template('invitation.html')
            message = "<p>%s, and an invitation to %s has been deferred from %s</p>" % (datetime.datetime.now(),recipient, user)
            context = {'recipient': recipient,
                        'message': message,
                        'current_time': current_time,
                        'user': user
                        }
            self.response.out.write(template.render(context))

            deferred.defer(send_invitation,recipient)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/sendinvite', SendInvitationHandler)], debug=True)
```

Change line `deferred.defer(send_invitation,recipient)` to `send_invitation(recipient)` and it works ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deferred task executes on a different handler in response to a different request, it no longer has the context of the original request. So basically you no longer have the `user` set.

You need to collect all the info required to send the message in the original context and pass it as parameter(s) to the deferred task. In your particular case you need to pass `user` as well, in addition to `recipient`, something like this:

```
def send_invitation(recipient, sender):

    mail.send_mail(sender=sender, to=recipient, 
                   subject='You\'re invited!',
                   body='''You have been invited to join our community...''')
```

and defer it with:

```
        deferred.defer(send_invitation, recipient, user)
```

Comment: Related note: globals are not your friend in python in general and on GAE in particular - they may be different when running on different instances. So use them with care (or avoid them altogether).

Comment: Tried the above and also the dict suggestion you edited using a dict. But sadly no difference; same error. invitation.send_invitation(recipient,user) is working no prob... but same behaviour with deffered.defer(recipient,user)

Comment: Did you notice the modified `send_invitation` argument list? You need 3 parameters for `deferred.defer`, not 2. Also - make sure you delete any previously deferred tasks - they may be re-tried and they'll still fail.

Comment: yes of course....did you not notice that two arguments are passed below... recipient & user          
invitation.send_invitation(recipient,user) is working no prob...                    
but same behaviour with deffered.defer(recipient,user) ...                     
 and of course the function was changed otherwise you would receive an error for passing more than one argument... that is very basic stuff

Comment: maybe related - try to move the `deferred.defer` call before `self.response.out.write`, just in case responding to the request wipes (some of) the original request context?

Comment: dont think that is it either... have moved the function to a seperate file/module ... and evening when importing and using as ''invitation.send_invitation(recipient,user)" ...still same behaviour

Comment: dont think that is it either... have moved the function to a seperate file/module ... and evening when importing and using as ''invitation.send_invitation(recipient,user)" ...still same behaviour

Comment: And you have `sender=<other_var_name>`, not `sender=user` in `mail.send_mail`, right?

Comment: yep its working.. to my shame I over looked the 'Email API authorized senders' in AppEngine .... Settings, not enough to set permissions/roles in IAM alone :-)